# How to get list of id's from one column which not contains in another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, data-analysis

pandas dataframe have two column which have list of id's need to get id,s which not contain in another columns

```
id  Column_1    Column_2
1   [1,2,5,7,9] [1,2,5,7]
2   [4,8,2,7]   [4,8,2,7]
3   [5,7,2,9]   [9] 
4   [4,7,2,9]   [3]


I want to  result like
id  Column_1    Column_2    result
1   [1,2,7]     [1,2,5,7,9] [5,9]
2   [4,8,2,7]   [4,8,2,7]   []
3   [5,7,2,9]   [9]         []
4   [4,7,2,9]   [3]         [3]
```

Comment: Convert lists to `set` and then make union `U` and intersection `I` of sets. After this you can get your result by subtracting `I` from `U`.

Comment: thanks user3053452 its working fine first i convert both columns into set and then subtract column_1 from column_2                                                                                                                        df['result']=df['column_2']-df['column_1']

Comment: While this might work in you current case, I'd like to point out that this is not the same. Becasue `A - B != B - A`. 
While `U- I=  (A - B) + (B - A)`

Answer (score 1):

Convert values to sets and get difference:

```
df['Column_3'] = [list(set(y).difference(x)) for x, y in zip(df['Column_1'], df['Column_2'])]
print (df)
   id      Column_1         Column_2 Column_3
0   1     [1, 2, 7]  [1, 2, 5, 7, 9]   [9, 5]
1   2  [4, 8, 2, 7]     [4, 8, 2, 7]       []
2   3  [5, 7, 2, 9]              [9]       []
3   4  [4, 7, 2, 9]              [3]      [3]
```